# How can I size a Form or a FlowLayoutPanel for printing larger than the Screen size?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing, flowlayoutpanel

I have a Form whose main panel is a FlowLayoutPanel that is exactly what I want to print (it is designed to look like a nicely formatted document... no buttons, etc. ... you right-click for commands).

So, I take advantage of DrawToBitmap to implement printing for almost free... I simply resize the Form such that the main panel is the size of the sheet of paper the user wants to print on (minus margins), which causes it to automatically flow its contents properly for that size.  I then just use DrawToBitmap to render that FlowLayoutPanel and all its contents to the printed page.  I can even scale to fit by growing the window larger than the page size (same aspect ratio), and then scaling down the Bitmap I get from DrawToBitmap.  Works great...

BUT it only works if your screen is larger than the page size!  Because any attempt to resize a Form or Control larger than the size of the screen + 12 pixels in either direction gets thwarted.

Ugh!!  Why tease me with the simplicity and utility of DrawToBitmap if you're going to kill its applicability by refusing to resize larger than the screen?  (rhetorical)

My questions:

Is there a way to circumvent that limit and get the Form or the FlowLayoutPanel to resize larger than the screen?

If not, is there a way to get to the FlowLayoutPanel's scrolled surface (not just the portion scrolled into view) such that I can size it to match the printed page and such that I can call DrawToBitmap on it?

If not, is there some other way to leverage my existing layout functionality to print?  Or am I stuck essentially rewriting all that WinForms code just to generate the same Bitmap it'll already generate if my screen is bigger than my printed page??

Comment: Have you actually looked at a printout?  You must have noticed how every pixel on the screen got turned into a 6x6 blob on paper.  Very ugly on anti-aliased text in particular.  Compare the output from PrintDocument before you commit to a lousy solution.

Comment: Yes, we've looked at the print outs... there are no 6x6 blobs.  The text is pretty smooth.  If we were doing a screen scrape (CopyFromScreen) then we'd see what you're talking about... but we're not.  We are doing DrawToBitmap which calls OnPrint instead of OnPaint, passing in the bitmap / device context generated from the printer... with its high DPI... so, when it draws text to that, it uses the printer's higher resolution (despite the pixel dimensions remaining the same).  It actually works surprisingly well.

Comment: With that said, it is NOT Postscript quality text... but our app is not trying to generate magazine-quality documents... it is an engineering app... and its plenty fine resolution for the engineers to be happy reading it (and drawing on it, etc).  But this admittedly would not be the best approach if you creating documents intended for publication or sales.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but would it be possible to do this all virtually. IE:

```
Dim FLP as FlowLayoutPanel = Form1.FlowLayoutPanel1
For Each flp_subobject as Object in FlowLayoutPanel.Children
    FLP.Children.Add(flp_subobject)
Next
FLP.Height = MASSIVEHEIGHT
FLP.Width = MASSIVEWIDTH
DrawToBitmapFunction(FLP)
```

That is how I would do it, not that I have much experience with regards to exceeding screen limits etc. Let me know how this goes, as it pretty much just came straight out of my head on the spot :D

Comment: I'm still experimenting, but it seems that all Control's Width and Height settings are max'd to the screen size.  I can reimplement the FlowLayoutPanel's logic such that I take a bitmap from each child and then assemble them flow-layout-wise onto the print surface myself... but I hate reinventing a wheel just because of one "max" variable.